# Behavioral and mood differences between D1 and D2 dophamine receptors action in context of monogamy and out of it

Tags: sexuality, behavior, mood

Claim: I initially thought of posting this to Biology SE, but the fact that the question finds its resting formation in the area of cognition/mood/personality, I decided to post it here.

It is stated that in respect to monogamic relationships in mammals, D2 receptors activation effect is important for initial male-female pair formation and D1 receptors activation effect is important for prolonging the relationship in time (up to death).

Since potentiation of D1 receptors and decrease in D2 receptors effect cannot limit itself to the context of these relationships, I wonder about how this change in the organism first changes the perception of its chosen mate and, later, affects its overal behavior, mood and cognition.

I would appreciate an answer along one or several of these lines, in the order of increasing interest:

- What behavioral traits can be attributed to each of these receptors actions?
- What changes in mood and mate perception/estimation/assesment can be spotted by a person affected by this process on various stages?
- What overall changes in perception of reality can be expected to manifest? I.e. how does this change translate to outside of the context of relationships and overall understanding/perception of reality?

References:

1. [Last sentences of the last paragraph](http://www.dana.org/News/Details.aspx?id=43517)
2. [Middle of the first page](https://www.genetics.ucla.edu/courses/hg19/monogamy.pdf)
3. [Somewhere near middle of the text](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2822034/)